# Django : How can I use the response returned by form_valid() of a CreateView on another model in a new template?

Tags: django, redirect, save, create-view

I am learning Django, and I am sure the solution is very simple but I can't find it; 
I have a model "profile" that needs to be filtered by a request. Requests and answers need to be kept in database. But I don't want the user to see all the profiles at any moment.
So I wrote two models : the first one contains the requests (MyRequest), the second the potential answers (Profile). Profiles are created importing csv in Django admin.
I wrote a code that is working fine BUT I can't figure out how to send my response in a template to use all the customizations and securities as csrf_token.

Currently it is showing the response in the same url than the request and I am blocked there

I have tried to use get_succes_url with HttpResponseRedirect, usually I can do such things using (?P\d+)/$' in the success url but it doesn't work maybe because the two models don't share any key? 
I have tried to put  and  in success url but I think I did something wrong

```
"""Models"""
class Profile(models.Model):#probgerme probpvt probservice probATCDpvt probATCDbmr probNB
    profname= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bq = models.ForeignKey(Bq, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#, blank=True
    test1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MyRequest(models.Model):#probgerme probpvt probservice probATCDpvt probATCDbmr probNB
    reqname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bq = models.ForeignKey(Bq, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=0, related_name="user2")
    test1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

"""Forms"""
class MyRequestCreateForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyRequest
        fields = ('bq','test1','test2')
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):       
        myrequest = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        myrequest.save()

"""URL """
url(r'^essai_create/$', views.MyRequestCreateView.as_view(), name='my_request'),


"""Views"""
class MyRequestCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView): 
    form_class = MyRequestCreateForm
    model = MyRequest
    def get_queryset(self):      
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
       form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['test1'].required = True 
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user 
        self.object = form.save()
        data = form.cleaned_data
        test1 = data['test1']
        test2 = data['test2']

        print('data',data)
        try:
            Profile.objects.get(test1 = test1, test2 = test2 )
            tested3= Profile.objects.get(test1 = test1, test2 = test2).test3.split(',')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            tested3 = ['nothing']*5           

        reponse = "Votre requête : test1 = " + test1 + ", test2 = " + test2 +    "<br>val1, "+tested3[0] + "<br>val2, "+tested3[1] + "<br>val3 " + tested3[2]+ "<br>val4, " + tested3[3]
        return HttpResponse(reponse)

"""Template myrequest_form.html"""

{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container ">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="project-form">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <form method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.bq|as_crispy_field }}
    <br>
      <div class="col-6">
        Information sur le test1 {{ form.test1 }} <br>
      </div>
        <br>
      <div class="col-6">
        Information sur le test2 {{ form.test2 }}<br>
      </div>
        <br>

<br><br>
         <button id = "submitRequest" aria-pressed="true" class="btn btn-primary active" onclick="showPleaseWait()"  type="submit"   >Check for best answer</button>
  </form>


  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Currently after clicking "Check for best answer" button in the template opened in http://localhost:8000/myapp/essai_create/, this same url
http://localhost:8000/myapp/essai_create/
shows:

Votre requête : test1 = nouveau, test2 = Rouge

val 1, 7

val 2, 12

val 3, 4

val 4, 5

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear. What is wrong with that output? What did you want to happen instead? What does this have to do with CSRF tokens?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, this output is fine but it is on the same url than the request and because of that it can't use a specific template.html with base.html and crsf token. I do not know how to pass this answer to a new template in a new url because I don't have a common key (pk) to use in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still finding it quite hard to understand what you want, unfortunately. Perhaps what you want is to find the Profile matching the submitted data, and then redirect to it? In which case you need to do that redirect inside `form_valid`, and define a DetailView for Profile that you redirect to. So:

```
class MyRequestCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView): 
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user 
        obj = form.save()
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(test1=obj.test1, test2=obj.test2)
            return redirect('profile', pk=profile.id)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('/')   # or wherever

class ProfileDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
```

and the URL:

```
path('profile_detail/<int:pk>', ProfileDetail, name='profile')
```

Comment: Thank you very much once more, it is really what I want to do; and it quite worked

 but if I write "obj = form.save()" then "Profile.objects.get(test1=obj.test1, etc)" localhost answers
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test1'
 and indeed form is set to be valid, self to be a MyRequestCreateView object at some internal address, and obj to be None and...

Comment: So, for the first problem the issue is in your form save method, which doesn't return the object. That method is pointless anyway, you should remove it and let it use the default implementation. For the second problem, are you sure you didn't create duplicate profiles while testing?

Comment: ...if I use "data=form.cleaned_data" and test1=data['test1']" etc, then Profile.objects.get('test1'=test1, etc) it answers "get() returned more than one ProbasProfile -- it returned 3!" and indeed it found "args () clone QuerySet [<Profile: test1, test2 >, <Profile: test1, test2>, <Profile: test1, test2> but I am sure there is a single profile for every possible test combination So I'm quite desperate!

Comment: Yes as I said, you  clearly have more than one Profile for that combination, probably  created during testing.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion here. This doesn't have anything to do with any of this code, or even your question. You just have three objects with the same values for test1 and test2. You should go into the admin and delete the duplicates.

Comment: No I am absolutely sure that I have only one profile per possible request I verified in admin mode that none was added inbetwwen, and with my too simple former method there is only one answer It is cloning three times the form data and I don't understand why, I thought of cache problem and tried in a private navigation window with new values for test1 and test2 : same problems with both methods

Comment: I will delete the database and try again Thank you very very much

Comment: I deleted the database, then had some troubles with the naming of urls and the location of templates but it is working fine now! Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman solution (creating a simple ProfileDetail view) is great! I only had to change the path (I am using Django 2.11) for

```
url(r'profiledetail/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ProfileDetail.as_view(), name='profile')
```

and needed to change the createview

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user 
    self.object = form.save()
    data = form.cleaned_data
    test1 = data['test1']
    test2 = data['test2']
    profile=ProbasProfile.objects.get(test1 = test1, test2=test2)
    return redirect('profile', pk=profile.id)
```

then in the new template created for the answer

```
{{profile.test1}}{{profile.test2}}{{profile.test3}}
```

and of course the class ProfileDetail as he wrote it